# Is it normal to have HDD fstrimed?

Tags: boot, trim

I have heavy boot issues on my new setting (more than 10 min to boot). While investigating, I found that:

```
$ journalctl -u fstrim
-- Reboot --
déc. 05 10:31:09 orphu systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
déc. 05 09:47:30 orphu fstrim[848]: /boot/efi: 63,2 MiB (66294784 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
déc. 05 09:47:30 orphu fstrim[848]: /: 282,9 GiB (303765995520 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda5
déc. 05 09:47:30 orphu systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
déc. 05 09:47:30 orphu systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
```

/dev/sda is an old school HDD, is it normal that fstrim spend to long trimming HDD ? How can I tell him not to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need fstrim on a spinning rust HDD. Disable the fstrim.service and fstrim.timer with the following.

```
rm /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-fstrim.timer
systemctl stop fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl disable fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl mask fstrim.service fstrim.timer
```